# How to query all Monticello packages from a Metacello Configuration?

Tags: version-control, smalltalk, pharo, monticello

I have a Metacello configuration like ConfigurationOfAthens and I want to know which packages provides, the result would be :

- Athens-Cairo
- Athens-CairoPools
- Athens-Core
- etc.

I tried

```
(GoferConfigurationReference name: 'ConfigurationOfAthens') packages.
```

but it is not understood by the system.

It this supported in Pharo 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the package names you could use helper classes to query from a Configuration. And so your query would be

```
(MTProject 
    newFromVersion: (ConfigurationOfAthens project version: #development)
    inConfiguration: ConfigurationOfAthens) dependenciesFilteredBy: MTPackage.
```

These MT classes - which sounds like they should belong to Metacello - are not in Metacello package, but currently in Versionner (included by default in Pharo images).

Diving into results reveals that some "MTPackages" has not their corresponding "RPackage" (this could be a bug, or some weird feature in the package representation models). So you would need further filtering:

```
((MTProject 
    newFromVersion: (ConfigurationOfAthens project version: #development)
    inConfiguration: ConfigurationOfAthens) dependenciesFilteredBy: MTPackage)
        select: [ :pkgName | 
            (RPackageOrganizer default 
                packageNamed: pkgName name asSymbol
                ifAbsent: []) notNil  ]
```

Comment: Reason why not all MTPackage have a corresponding RPackage is that not all packages in a configuration needs to end inside the image (for example, different platform packages, etc.). If you want to know which packages will be loaded (without loading it), you need to use #record.